# How can I improve load performance of Angular2 apps?

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, angular2-routing, systemjs

Angular2 app is loading slow, how can I improve the performance on load?

I use Angular2, typescript with html5.

currently my app takes 4 seconds to load.
I host with Firebase and use cloudflare.

**Things I'm doing / info:**

- I've compressed images.
- I minify css
- I minify js.
- I use async on my scripts.
- My scripts are in my .
- The scripts are around 700kb
- I used google speed test and get 65%
- I used minified version of the libs I use e.g. bootstrap etc.
- Using systemjs.
- This is the seed app im using: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

**Flow:**

When the app loads it shows a blue screen (this is the bootstrap css) and then 4 seconds later the app loads and works really fast. But takes 4 seconds to load. It seems the app.js file that systemjs minifies to is slowing the whole app, and not showing the views fast enough.

**This is my website speed test:** 
https://www.webpagetest.org/result/161206_F5_N87/

**This is my website:**

https://thepoolcover.co.uk/

Let me know if you need more information about my app and any other things I can do.

Comment: I closed this question because the topic is too broad to cover in a few paragraphs here. A full answer would require many pages or even an entire book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about "code splitting".

From the Webpack site:

"For big web apps it’s not efficient to put all code into a single file, especially if some blocks of code are only required under some circumstances. Webpack has a feature to split your codebase into “chunks” which are loaded on demand. Some other bundlers call them “layers”, “rollups”, or “fragments”. This feature is called “code splitting”.

Link here:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Note that the Angular CLI uses Webpack.

Also, make sure that if your app bootstraps with data calls, that you are not holding up the rendering of your components waiting on those calls to return. Promises, async, etc.

Comment: Do you have a solution that doesn't require webpack. I've tried async and defer

Comment: It'd be impossible to provide anything other than general guidelines without knowing the specifics of you how bootstrap your app; what assets are loading, what data calls are you making, are you hitting any external APIs, doing any drawing of any kind, laying out a lot of items in repeats, etc. Unless you're doing something really obviously wonky, that could take some real time to figure out. The best I could do at this point is say, look at the timeline in the developer tools, and see what's holding it up.

Comment: is seems to be cloudflare causing the issue. I ran a speed test. Have you ever had issues with cloudflare or know much about them?

Comment: Tim. when you  say: "Also, make sure that if your app bootstraps with data calls, that you are not holding up the rendering of your components waiting on those calls to return. Promises, async, etc." Do you mean the app.component? I have calls their. Could those be effecting the loading of the app?

Comment: Absolutely. If your app is waiting for data to return before it starts rendering the first component (app), then your app is just going to sit there blank until that data call returns.

Comment: @AngularM that i already mentioned in my 6th point. Yes it was not specific but it was same.

Comment: Is code splitting possible with angular-cli? I have been using non-aot compile and the size is still substantial.

Comment: It should be. I don't use the CLI anymore but I can't imagine they'd prevent it or make it difficult, it's a major feature of WebPack.

Answer (score 120):

A single page application generally takes more time while loading as it loads all necessary things at once.

I had also faced same problem and my team has optimized our project from loading in 8 seconds to 2 seconds by using following methods.

1. **Lazy loading a module :**  Lazy loading modules helps to decrease the startup time. With lazy loading our application does not need to load everything at once, it only needs to load what the user expects to see when the app first loads. Modules that are lazily loaded will only be loaded when the user navigates to their routes. Angular2 has introduced modules in its final release RC5. **See below for step-by-step guide.**
2. **Aot Compilation :**  With AoT, the browser downloads a pre-compiled version of the application. The browser loads executable code so it can render the application immediately, without waiting to compile the app first.

   *It reduces the payload size :* There's no need to download the Angular compiler     if the app is already compiled. The compiler is roughly half of Angular itself, so omitting it dramatically reduces the application payload. For more info see [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html).
3. **Webpack :** Webpack is a popular module bundler, a tool for bundling    application source code in convenient chunks and for loading that code from a server into a browser. You can configure your Angular 2 web application with webpack (see [this guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)).
4. **Remove scripts,stylesheet from index.html :** Remove all scripts and stylesheet which are not needed in index.html. You can load these script dynamically in component itself by calling a service.

   Make a file script.service.ts which can load any script on demand for that component

\script.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var document: any;

@Injectable()
export class Script {

  loadScript(path: string) {
    //load script
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = path;
      if (script.readyState) {  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = () => {
          if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            resolve({ loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
          }
        };
      } else {  //Others
          script.onload = () => {
            resolve({ loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
          };
      };
      script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({ loaded: false, status: 'Loaded' });
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    });
  }
}
```

This is just a sample code to load script dynamically, you can customize and optimize it by yourself according to your need.
For stylesheet you should load it in component using styleUrl.

5. **Use Browser Caching :** Your webpage files will get stored in the browser cache when you use browser caching. Your pages will load much faster for repeat visitors and so will other pages that share those same resources. For more info https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html
6. **minimize the code in app.component.ts :** minimize the code present in app.component.ts which always run when the app loads or reloads.
7. **set data on app Initialization :** if you are using same api calls multiple times in your project or in components, 
   or you are dependent upon same data in multiple component, instead of calling api multiple times what you can do is save
   the data as an object in service on app initialization. That service will act as a singleton throughout the project and you 
   can access that data without calling api.

---

**Lazy loading of modules step by step**

1. **Modular structure :** We have to divide our App into separate modules. For example an app may have a user side and an admin side and each will have its own different components and routes, so we will separate this two sides into modules admin.module.ts and user.module.ts.
2. **Root Module :** Every Angular app has a root module class. By convention it's a class called AppModule in a file named app.module.ts , this module will import the above two module and also the AppComponent for bootstrap. You can also declare multiple components according to your need. Sample code in app.module.ts:

\app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [UserModule, AdminModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. **Routes :**  Now in your routes you can specify like the following

\app.router.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: 'LoginComponent' }, //eager loaded
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }, // Lazy loaded module
  { path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule' }  //lazy loaded module
];
```

Now when the application loads, it will only load LoginComponent and AppComponent code. These modules will only be loaded when we visit /admin or /user routes. Hence it will decrease the size of payload for loading into the browser, thus resulting in fast loading.

4. **Nesting Modules :** Just like app.module every module has its own set of components and routes. As your project becomes larger, the nesting of modules inside module is the best way to optimize because we can lazily load those modules whenever we require.

---

**PLEASE NOTE**

Above code is only for explanation, please refer for full example 
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: I've added more info about my app at the top in the question

Comment: Can you add the steps on how to add Lazy loading a module e.g. the exact steps for me to follow?

Comment: @AngularM you can reference this for help on lazy loading:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: i have given some explanation now on how you can leverage lazy load of modules step by step. And if you want a sample project to implement i can make a github repo just tell me because this post will become huge if i do here. To implement lazy load you should know module and router concepts in final release of Angular  2.

Comment: @VikashDahiya I am trying to lazy load. And I have put a console.log in the module constructor. When the app instantiates it does instantiate the lazy module also which means they are downloaded, loaded when the app instantiates. Can you recheck if that is what lazy load does?

Comment: @Gary you can check your network in browser when you navigate to that particular module. You can see that module will be there which consist required html.

Comment: @Gary also notice that different chunk loads when you navigate to different module in your browser network.

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult to diagnose the precise problem you are having without hands-on to your entire code base and backend (as others have suggested, the problem may not be angular at all).

Having said that, I HIGHLY recommend you start using the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).  It was designed by the angular team to accomplish all of the things you need to do in a easy-to-use command line interface. So my answer is predicated on the use of the angular-cli.

Here are the general things you can do to optimize your ng2 project for production:

**1) Ahead of Time (AoT) Compilation - Bundling/Minification/Tree-shaking**

Look, forget about the headache of configuring a bunch of gulp tasks to accomplish all of these things. The angular-cli handles Bundling/Minification/Tree-shaking/AOT compilation in one easy step:

> ng build -prod -aot

This will produce the following js files in your "dist" folder:

```js
inline.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js
vendor.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js
main.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js
styles.4cec2bc5d44c66b4929ab2bb9c4d8efa.bundle.css
```

You will also get the gzipped versions of these files for MORE optimization:

```
inline.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js.gz
vendor.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js.gz
main.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js.gz
```

Angular's AOT compilation will automatically do "tree shaking" on your code and get rid of any unused references.  For example, you may use lodash in your project, but you probably only use a few lodash functions; tree shaking will trim away all the unused parts of lodash that are not needed in your final build.  And most importantly, AOT compilation will pre-compile all of your code and views which means LESS time the browser needs to get the ng2 app rolling.  [Click here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) for more info on angular's AOT compilation.

**2) Lazy loading parts of your app**
If you further carve up your app into different parts, you do not need to load EVERYING when your app first loads.  You can specify different modules for your application that then can be bundled (by the angular-cli aot compiler) into different chunks.  Read up [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) to learn how to organize your project into modules that you can compile into chucks that are only loaded AS NEEDED. Angular-cli will manage the creation of these chunks for you.

**3) Angular Universal**
Now if you really want to make your load time EXTREMELY fast then you will want to consider implementing [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal), which is when you compile your initial view ON THE SERVER.  I have not used Angular Universal as I have been able to achieve fast load times with steps 1 and 2. But it is an exciting option in the ng2 toolset.  Keep in mind you don't compile or run the ng2 app on the server, you compile the initial view serverside so the user quickly receives a jolt of html and thus the user PERCEIVES the load time to be very fast (even though a full load will still lag behind a little bit).  This step does not obviate the need for the other steps.  As a bonus, Angular Universal also is supposed to help with SEO.

**4) Secondary bundling**

If I am not using lazy loading, I usually go ahead and further bundle the distribution files that are generated from AOT compilation.  Thus I create one **main.bundle.js** file that concats inline.js, vendor.js and main.js files.  I use gulp for this.

Comment: `angular-cli` currently does not support aot see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1732. The option is there, but for many projects it will not work.

Comment: I have been using AOT compilation with angular-cli for well over a month now.   I'll admit, you do need to clean/debug your code to get pre-compile errors out of the way, but it is working just fine for me.

Comment: FYI, I just did AOT compilation on angular2's 'tour of heros' app, the version using lazy loading etc. had no problems...

Comment: @shusson angular-cli supports **AOT and lazy-loading** very well. The only things that doesn't work, is if you have custom decorators (when using @ngrx/effects for example). Indeed, customs decorators are stripped out ...

Comment: @brando @maxime it's great that it works for you guys but based on github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1732 there are more than a few people who are having issues with it. I think `angular-cli` is great but until that issue is resolved we should be cautious recommending `angular-cli` aot builds to people.

Comment: @shusson I've added more info about my app at the top in the question

Comment: I am trying to lazy load. And I have put a console.log in the module constructor. When the app instantiates it does instantiate the lazy module also which means they are downloaded, loaded when the app instantiates. Does it really work with ng-cli which puts all into one bundle

Comment: This is probably the most comprehensive, yet easy-to-understand answer on making modern Angular (4+) apps load and render more quickly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

because its SPA and angular 2 init too slow. thats it. plus RXjs, tons of polifills etc. AOT can help but a lot of angular2 libs do not work with it. angular universal realy helps

Comment: I don't have a server side. My apps front end only. Any alternatives?

Comment: for now i know only one good solution: aot. with caveat written earlier. + lazy load. but it has small impact.  for speeding up development i use @angularclass/hmr(from this example https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). its really really fast and remember all your input data

Comment: I currently use aot

Answer (score 1):

Build your angular app using following command to get maximum optimization benefits.

```
ng build --prod --aot --optimization --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --extract-licenses --extract-css --source-map=false
```

Basically you will build in aot mode and use treeshaking with some optimization.

- optimization: Enables optimization of the build output.
- vendor-chunk: Use a separate bundle containing only vendor libraries.
- common-chunk: Use a separate bundle containing code used across multiple bundles.
- extract-css: Extract css from global styles onto css files instead of js ones.
- build-optimizer: Enables @angular-devkit/build-optimizer optimizations when using the 'aot' option.
- source-map=false: remove source map will also reduce bundle size

Answer (score -5):

Try disabling source maps by running `ng serve --sourcemap=false`