# how to speed up angularJs 4 on first time load?

Tags: angular

I am using **angularJs 4** , when i hit the project url at first time in any other system it takes a while to load the project.

Is there a way to speed the angularJs project on first time run?

Comment: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135 May be it would help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894704/how-can-i-improve-load-performance-of-angular2-apps :- may be this will help you out...

Comment: Refer AoT(Ahead of time) compilation
https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind` will help you to handle this problem as angular will behave light will loading its content. Have a look at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)