# Angular 4+ App slow rendering on mobile

Tags: javascript, angular, rendering

My angular app runs terribly slow in mobile so I carried a test and found out that the javascript execution time (after the bundle.js gets loaded) is the main bottle neck. There's a huge difference in them between desktop to that on a mobile.

What might be causing the problem and what might be the possible solutions?

Test for desktop
[image]

Test for mobile(Moto G)
[image]

You can see the JS Execution time is denoted by the purple bar.

Comment: Is it running with ng serve or you took the production build?

Comment: I'm testing on production build, and it's build with aot and lazy loading

Comment: Enabling AOT (AOT to true) may work!

Comment: Is this still the case? I'm deciding if we should use angular 2+ for our mobile app or if we should swap to react?

Comment: No, it's not the case now, but react is faster anyway

Comment: on our app we found that zone.js was the root of the problem of slowing down our app, which still an issue not solved by angular and zone.js team. Also make sure to unsubscribe your observables on ondestroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the page speed suggestions by Google for your site.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Faiesec.org&tab=mobile

Try to make the changes mentioned and test again to see if it makes it any better.

Move the render blocking js to the footer. That's the one thing I noticed when checked the source from my mobile.

Please have a look at the below question

[How can I improve load performance of Angular2 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40894704/2295484)

I have seen the initial slow issue on many angular apps even though they have been optimized with production build. Please have a look at that it may help.

Comment: Thanks for that, while I agree there has to be some optimizations suggested in there, but you can see the difference between fcp and dcl values for desktop and mobile. All the optimization techniques given there focus on less network load, wouldn't that of not any effect to this difference?

Also main rendering blocking js in my case bundle.js gets generated by angular itself and it is the part of the main application