# Angular web application take so long to load

Tags: angular, web-applications, google-chrome-devtools, loading

I'm trying to figure out what takes so long to load on the web application we are building.
Here's the chrome developer tool network tab

Why is there a gap between scripts/stylesheet and the HTML?

[image: Chrome Network]

Comment: The gap between the vendor bundle being fully downloaded and starting to fetch e.g .`beta-banner-left.png` is presumably where the interpreter is loading and bootstrapping the Angular application.

Comment: Would there be a way to improve the loading time?

Comment: Did you do any research? Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40894704/3001761

Answer (score 0):

Load your library JS and relative css files from CDN location. It will give good performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `--prod` flag for your `ng serve` or `ng build`

- `ng serve --prod`
- `ng build --prod`